# How do I access a file whose contents is in memory rather than on disk?

Tags: linux, memory, command

Say that there is a command line like:

```
interpreter afile bfile opt1 opt2 ...
```

where `afile` `bfile` are two disk files, other are options.

but in my case `afil`e and `bfile` content are in memory, and for reasons I cannot write them onto disk.

How to execute the cmd in this case?

btw, on Linux.
Thanks

Comment: Where in memory are these files and how did they get there?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know this rule before... Many thanks.

Comment: @Fuzzyfelt Acctually, this cmd is called in another c++ program with `exec` method. Usually, `afile`, `bfile` are real files, but in some case, we can only provide a `char*` like string/bytearray as the file content.

Comment: @zhangailin This is relatively complex situation. There is no such concept of accesible "files in memory" (outside of ram disks). Assuming the other program is still running then you will have to find a method to communicate with it. I'm not an expert on this but I think this could be shared memory, unix sockets or named pipes.

Answer (score 2):

If you really like these so called 'files' to be visible to other third-party programs as files you have two options:

- develop a program, let's call it *getfile* for the sake of this answer, that may provide the content of these files at its stdout, then you may use it this way:

  ```
  interpreter <(getfile afile) <(getfile bfile) opt1 opt2 ...
  ```
- implement a [FUSE](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/) (filesystem in userspace) filesystem that will expose these 'files' as regular files in a mountable filesystem. In this case you just mount this filesystem and access the files as regular files:

  ```
  interpreter /path/to/mount/point/afile /path/to/mount/point/bfile opt1 opt2 ...
  ```

Comment: THe OP might have some `tmpfs` mounted filesystem, then the files are sitting in (virtual) memory.